# ddr3 content after intialization

Tags: memory, xilinx, sdram, ddr3

I am verifying a memory interface to MIG IP from Xilinx.
The MIG IP is connected to a ddr3 SDRAM from Micron. I have a ddr3 model from Micron that I included in my testbench.

I waited until the initialization of the SDRAM is done by MIG and then I started reading.
I assumed that the SDRAM content after initialization is zero for all addresses but when I send a read command to the memory, I am getting random data read back from memory.

**Is the SDRAM after initialization empty or have some random data?**

Comment: SDRAM has no reset mechanism for the device contents. If you want to model what real SDRAM does, make the simulation model initialise itself with random data (or read a file of random data).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am not concern about the model. the requirement I have is that the memory must be cleared to zero before the system can use it. It seems that I have to code a memory clearing function after memory initialization.

Comment: Making the model more accurate would allow you to test that function in simulation.

Answer (score 5):

SDRAM is indeterminate at power-on.  So many models will randomize content to help expose errors coming from assuming that the power-on state will be determinate.

Answer (score 0):

‘DRAM initialization’ in the context of a memory controller means setting up the DRAM and controller mode and timing parameters, and performing some initial row access cycles to get the memory to a useable state for the host.

It does *not* mean initializing the data: post-initialization the DRAM data state is still unknown even though it’s functional. There’s more work to do, and we’ll get to that in a moment.

Who does this DRAM and controller init? The pre-boot code that’s run by the host at cold reset. In older systems this would be a boot ROM, nowadays it would be an image copied from flash to host SRAM buffer. Either way, the MIG doesn’t do it by itself, the host does it by software.

Once the host DRAM + MIG init is complete, the booting process continues - diags, BIOS or its equivalent, kernel, etc. - all the steps needed to make a running system. Some of these steps will not only load code, but will reserve and clear blocks of blank, zeroed-out memory. Again, all done by the host, not the MIG.

Comment: I am not using a host pc or an OS. So, I have to code a block that writes zero to all memory addresses after initialization?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. You will need something to write zeroes to the memory ahead of using it. If you have specialty processor blocks, perhaps extend them to run in zero-out mode for an initial pass.